# Override id selector in different .css file

Tags: html, css

```
#logo {
float: left;
margin: 0;
}
```

in a .css file.

I can not edit this .css file but use another instead
I want to deactivate the `float: left;`

How can I override the rules for the `id="logo"`

I tried

```
#logo {
float: none !important;
margin: 0;
}
```

in the other .css file

but it does not override

This is a snapshot of the HTML code:

```
<div id="header">   
    <div id="logo">
        <img ...>
    </div><!-- end of #logo -->
</div>
```

I also tried to use a more specific selector which only selects a `id="logo"` which is in a div with the `id="header"` but could not get it to work with my .css knowledge and tutorials

Thanks, for your help!

Comment: What you say you've tried should work. Can you create a jsFiddle.net example of the problem?

Comment: Is your file added to the page before or after the file you are unable to change? Float none should clear the previous float even with the same specificity if added afterwards. There may be an inline value or more specific value in another file - have you looked in your browser dev tools to see what is going on? Are you definite it is float and not another style which is causing the layout you are seeing?